# S3 Download file very slow

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a dynamic image resizing function in Lambda, hwoever it is very slow.

I am using python with Boto3 to check for an item in the bucket, however this process is very slow, sometimes taking up to 3-4 seconds.

```
def check_image_s3(imagekey):

    try:
        response = s3.meta.client.get_object(Bucket = 'stylezz-images', Key= imagekey)
        image_exists = True
    except:
        # except ClientError:
        image_exists = False

    return image_exists
```

Is there a quicker way to check if an object exists within a bucket?

Comment: Do you have the Lambda function in the same AWS region as the S3 bucket?

Comment: Benchmark.  Log the current time at multiple places in your code.  I will venture a guess that the "slow" doesn't happen where you assume it does... but, question: if the object is there, do you actually want its payload, or do you just want to know it exists?